# Do I need to uninstall Ubuntu to upgrade to Windows 8?

Tags: uninstall, windows-8

All that was an awesome experience using Ubuntu 12.04. I want to upgrade my Windows 7 to Windows 8.

So do I need to uninstall my Ubuntu (as a Precaution)? Right now I have both the operating systems on my Laptop. If I have to uninstall please tell me the procedure.

Comment: Back everything up first!

Answer (score 2):

If you used wubi.exe i would uninstall it. I made the mistake of not uninstalling it now when I try to boot to Ubuntu I get an error screen.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not. You can upgrade to windows 8. As long as you only modify your windows partition this will be fine. After you install windows 8 you will no longer be able to boot into linux because grub will have been replaced, but you can just put it back using a rescue cd.

Start the rescue cd then run something like

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt

sudo grub-install /dev/sda --boot-directory=/mnt/boot/
```

adjusting the command for your hard drive partitions and locations.